# 2 Corinthians 12:7 where was the thorn located exactly?

Tags: pneumatology, 2-corinthians, demons

> “So to keep me from becoming conceited because of the surpassing greatness of the revelations, **a thorn was given me in the flesh**, a messenger of Satan to harass me, to keep me from becoming conceited.”
> ‭‭2 Corinthians‬ ‭12:7‬ ‭

This is not asking what is the thorn, it’s clearly a messenger “angel” aggelos of satan.

The question is where is this thorn, aggelos located exactly? Is he outside of Paul bothering Paul from the outside, on the surface, skin deep or inside the meat, inside the body (cavity) of Paul? Inside his biological machine, inside the human body?

Comment: This is a question debated through the centuries with no consensus.

Comment: Let’s give up @PerryWebb shut down this stack!

Comment: But, I would expect a very long detailed answer of all the conjectures.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's problem with his eyesight has been a favored speculation even among many commentators to be his "thorn in the flesh". We do know from Gal. 6:11 that Paul seems to have had some type of deficiency with his eyes. But what the thorn was seems very clearly defined in the context of 2 Cor. 11 and 12. Paul uses three different descriptive terms all of which refer to the same thing. He calls it a 'thorn in the flesh,' a 'messenger from Satan,' and 'my weaknesses.'

These weaknesses are not of a singular nature. They are described as insults, distresses, persecutions, and difficulties, all of which are in the plural. I do not doubt that his seeming deficiency with his eyes would certainly fall within this menagerie of weaknesses. The 'thorn in the flesh' is simply a descriptive term which Paul employed to describe a host of things he was called to endure for the cause of Christ. Their purpose was to keep him humble in the midst of his exalted position. It is hard to be proud and self-exalting when someone is beating the hide off of your back with a scourge or breaking your bones with rods or stoning you. These types of experiences are by their very nature, humbling.

Let us open up the context of 2 Cor. 11 and 12.

The context is Paul's defense of his apostleship. If one was able to boast according to the standard of the flesh, then Paul had more reason to boast than anyone else and he begins to compile a list of reasons to prove why this was true, 11:16-28. Beginning in verse 22, Paul says,

"Are they Hebrews? So am I. Are they Israelites? So am I. Are they descendants of Abraham? So am I."

These are all genealogical factors that he has in common with all other Jews. Then in verse 23, he begins to set forth a list of comparisons in which he is proven to excel above them all.

"Are they servants of Christ? (I speak as if insane) I MORE SO; in far more labors, in far more imprisonments, beaten times without number, often in danger of death. Five times I received from the Jews thirty-nine lashes. Three times I was beaten with rods, once I wa sstoned, three times I was shipwrecked, a night and a day I have spent in the deep. I have been on frequent journeys, in dangers from rivers, dangers from robbers, dangers from my countrymen, dangers from the Gentiles, dangers in the city, dangers in the wilderness, dangers on the sea, dangers among false brethren; I have been in labor and hardship, through many sleepless nights, in hunger and thirst, often without food, in cold and exposure. Apart from such external things, there is the daily pressure on me of concern for all the churches. From 11:29 through 12:8 he stresses the fact that these are all things that Paul regards as weaknesses of the flesh. These are things that are hard to endure and that he had the right to boast in the fact that he has suffered in the flesh more than all of them. In 12:6 he says that he does not wish to boast in these things, "... but I refrain from this, so that no one will credit me with more than he sees in me or hears from me."

In verse 7, he gives the paramount reason for his capacity for boasting which was “the surpassing greatness of the revelations.” To keep him from boasting and exalting himself in this, he was given a “thorn in the flesh.” The “thorn” represents something that is external to the flesh but that is intrusive to the flesh. In spite of his petition for God to remove it, God says, “My grace is sufficient for you.” It was not through Paul's own power that he was able to endure the suffering that had been imposed upon his flesh (not to mention the psychological stress that accompanies these types of experiences), it was the grace of God that enabled him to endure them and to continue to preach in spite of them. The connecting statement that links all of this to gather is in verse 10 when Paul says, “THEREFORE.” Whatever he says next is rooted in everything he has said up to this point and he connects it to the thorn that was given him.

"Therefore, I am well content with weaknesses, insults, distresses, persecutions, and difficulties for Christ's sake.”

Why? Because,

“when I am weak THEN I am strong.”

The thorn made him weak. The grace made him strong. NOW, he is able to rejoice in his sufferings - in his thorn. So, because of “the surpassing greatness of the revelations,” Paul was allowed to suffer all of these hardships - his thorn in the flesh - in order to keep him from exalting himself. One is not so likely to be self-exalting when he is having the hide stripped from his back with a scourge or having to go hungry or floating around in the sea or having his bones broken from being beaten with rods or lying in a pit left for dead after having been stoned. God allowed these things so that Paul would learn humility in spite of the exalted status that God had granted him. Remember what God told Ananias in Acts 9:16, “I will show him how much he must suffer for My name's sake.”

Comment: +1 Very nicely worded and all from the scriptures themselves. Thank you.

Comment: Did you miss the part in the description of the question that reads *”This is not asking what is the thorn”*?  The question is where is this aggelos located? Inside Paul, or outside Paul? You’ve side stepped the whole question by focusing on what I specifically said the question is not about.

Answer (score 1):

It is external. We can ‘see’ this if we examine closely.

This is speaking about Paul being so respected and honored in the sight of people that Satan had to do something to make him and his Gospel less attractive. He did that through persecution.

One of the reasons people think Paul’s thorn was sickness is because of the use of the word “infirmities” in 2 Corinthians 12:9-10. They presume “infirmities” is referring to some type of sickness. However, the word “infirmities” in context is referring to persecution.

Infirmities - Greek ‘*astheneia*’ - to be made weak. Weakness, frailty.

The Lord didn’t redeem Stephen from persecution but used it to glorify Himself and prick the heart of the future Apostle Paul. And, importantly, we are nowhere promised to be ‘free’ or ‘escape’ persecution - so Paul asking for this had zero scriptural promise or claim to back this up -hence it was denied.

The phrase “thorn in the flesh” was not original with Paul. It was an Old Testament term that referred to the negative influence ungodly people had on righteous people.

**Numbers 33:55** *But if you do not drive out the inhabitants of the land from before you, then it shall be that those whom you let remain shall be irritants in your eyes and thorns in your sides, and they shall* **harass** *you in the land where you dwell.*

**Judges 2:3** *Therefore I also said, ‘I will not drive them out before you; but they shall be thorns in your side, and their gods shall be a snare to you.’*

Paul drew on O.T. terminology to refer to the persecution he had suffered.

Further examples of Paul’s persecutions and infirmities are given in Acts 9:23, 26-29; 13:6-12, 44-50; 14:1-19; 16:12-40; 17:1-14; 18:1-23; 19:23-31; and 20:3.

So, the ‘*angel*’ sent to buffer Paul was *outside* of him. This angel generated or rather motivated *others* to ‘give this apostle a hard time’.

Comment: “Thorn IN the flesh” is what then, an expression? It’s the first thing he mentions, and it’s followed by an explanation. Surely in the FLESH is emphasizing its physical and the buffeting or the consistent/repeated blows again indicates physicality. Are you choosing to say outside for theological reasons and therefore any ramifications it would have that Paul might have been harassed by a demon from the inside? Or do you have something more concrete that it was definitely from the outside? Are you saying it would have been impossible for Paul to have been struck from the inside as a Christian?

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo A thorn **in** your side - Paul is using Torah to explain, ‘*thorn in your side*’ - tsad, contr. from an unused root meaning to sidle off; a side; figuratively, **an adversary**. One who (from the outside) afflicts you. Affliction is (can) only ever be to your flesh! That’s the trouble with my (any) response - if it doesn’t ‘fit’ the questioners ‘theology’ - ( in this case, looking for ‘demonic influence’ - for others not being a ‘sickness’.) it’s going to be rejected. Nevertheless- An angel is **not** a demon!

Comment: Thanks for projecting.

Comment: *“For I know that nothing good dwells in me, that is, **in my flesh**. For I have the desire to do what is right, but not the ability to carry it out.”
‭‭Romans‬ ‭7:18‬* ‭when the lying spirit acted on the prophets of Ahab did it act from the outside or the inside? Clearly it can be from the inside. As to whether it is exclusively from the inside is another matter.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo [you wrote - *emphasis mine*] “*Clearly* **it** *can be from the inside.*” You seem to making an inference as to what ‘it’ is - [demonic force?] - but the context of Romans 7 clearly reflects the ‘it’ = ‘sin’. All ‘sin’ is ‘in’ the flesh - and it is that (sinful flesh) that the messenger (angel) was both attempting to provoke and as well attack it (flesh) [from the outside]. A believer can have a spirit oppress him [from the outside] but *can not* have any other ‘spirit’ *in* him - impossible! (But that’s another discussion.)

Comment: That’s not impossible for a BELIEVER to have a spirit inside of them, not according to Jesus. “And he said to her, *“Let the children be fed first, for it is not right to take the children’s bread and throw it to the dogs.””
‭‭Mark‬ ‭7:27‬* and the bread was deliverance from unclean spirits. Meaning deliverance is for the children or the believers not the unbelievers. But you’ve answered my question already. Your argument that a believer cannot have an unclean spirit inside is purely theological and not Scriptural.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo I didn’t say a believer couldn’t have a ‘spirit’ *in* them, I said they couldn’t have *another* [meaning: unclean/demonic] spirit in them. And that can be exegetically argued!- but as I said previously, that’s another discussion. You also have an ‘interesting’ interpretation of Mark 7:27 - I’d be keen to see a question asked that would allow discussion of that.

Comment: The point is not just another spirit but an unclean spirit otherwise deliverance (bread for the children) would not be needed. As for a question on that text, it already exists.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo Yes, that Q RE: Mark 7:27 exists, but because you asked it, neither the the Q, nor any answers reflect any background to what you stated here - “*and the bread was deliverance from unclean spirits*”. It’s obvious you have a different view of this passage (which is possibly why no answers were accepted?) - and it’s that (your view) I’m curious about. (As well as what you think an ‘*unclean*’ spirit is?). But we can’t [shouldn’t be] doing any of that via ‘comments’.

Answer (score 0):

19Now the works of the flesh are evident: sexual immorality, impurity, sensuality, 20idolatry, sorcery, enmity, strife, jealousy, fits of anger, rivalries, dissensions, divisions, 21envy, drunkenness, orgies, and things like these. I warn you, as I warned you before, that those who do such things will not inherit the kingdom of God.

— Galatians 5:19–21

Comment: Hey and welcome Catherine. a 'thorn in the flesh,' is a 'messenger of some sort from Satan (2 Corinthians 12:7)  I don't see your answer fit the question, please edit it and expand on your thought to get up votes. God bless!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that we are not told anything about what Paul's "thorn in the flesh" was, except that God used it to keep him humble, has not prevented much speculation.  Here are some suggestions:

- Poor eyesight based on a his remark in Gal 6:11 but this is a strained interpretation
- Bouts of irregular mental depression based on the many persecutions and trials he endure as recorded in 2 Cor 1:8-10, but this cannot be proved
- Some physical frailty such as being partially crippled, regular dyspepsia, various chronic aches and pains, etc, etc.

All such speculation is precisely that and is pointless.  We are not told.

Comment: I’m asking about the aggelos, where did he act on Paul from? The exterior or the interior?

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - the text does not restrict it to either - that is, it could have been internal or external.

Comment: Not told what is was? ... “*a messenger of Satan*”. We are told exactly what it is! The problem is a literal interpretation doesn’t ‘fit’ what some want this to mean.